# Trigger Azure DevOps pipeline from another pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I was looking at the azure triggers [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops) and still not able to find an appropriate solution.
How during the execution of pipeline 1 can you trigger pipeline 2, wait for it to successfully finish or fail, and based on pipeline 2 results either continue execution of pipeline 1 or fail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How during the execution of pipeline 1 can you trigger pipeline 2, wait for it to successfully finish or fail, and based on pipeline 2 results either continue execution of pipeline 1 or fail?

Trigger one pipeline after another, it will run your pipeline upon the successful completion of the triggering pipeline. We cannot use it to trigger pipeline 1 in the execution of pipeline 1.

As a workaround:

a. We can add task power shell and add script to call the REST API to queue the build.

```
$connectionToken="PAT"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
$PipelineUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{project name}/_apis/pipelines/{Pipeline ID}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1" 

$body ="{ 
 `"resources`":{
        `"repositories`":{
            `"self`":{`"refName`":`"refs/heads/master`"
            }
         }
    }
}"
$Pipelines = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PipelineUrl -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method POST
```

b. Add task power shell and enter the code `Start-Sleep -Seconds 1000` to sleep the pipeline 1

c. Add the task power shell in the pipeline 1 to get the pipeline 2 build result via the [REST API,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) and set the result as env variable.

d. Configure the [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in the next task to check the env variable value. If the value is `succeeded`, continue run the pipeline 1

Comment: I can't believe this is the only way to achieve this. To me the way dependant pipelines have been implemented in Azure DevOps is backwards - why would the dependant pipeline need to know about it's parent? The dependency should be the other way around surely

Comment: @David Masters - We've been using the Trigger Build Task extension which has worked out very well (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks).  The author has done a great job with it and responds well to github questions.  I agree with you about the dependency being the other way around, which is a problem this extension solves.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like this.

```
# this is being defined in app-ci pipeline
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: securitylib   # Name of the pipeline resource
    source: security-lib-ci # Name of the pipeline referenced by the pipeline resource
    trigger: 
      branches:
      - releases/*
      - master
```

its right there in the link, you have linked, but in the sibling section of the docs. I am surprised you missed it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Thanks, Jay for your response. I looked at that option, but this solution doesn't stop the current pipeline execution and only triggers the second pipeline after execution is complete. From the docs: "trigger to run your pipeline upon the successful completion of the triggering pipeline. What I need is to stop pipeline A until pipeline execution B is complete. Then based on results from pipeline B, either continue with execution of pipeline A or stop.

Comment: Ah, right, of course, I am assuming a two pipeline scenario, so does the article. the thing is, from my understanding, YAML is not javascript. its more like a river flowing down a mountain. You can route things, but not loop back. if I were you, I would build 3 pipelines. pipeline 1 triggers pipeline 2, and then, based on what comes out of pipeline 2, I trigger the next pipeline 3 (your first pipeline, broken down into pipeline 1 and 3 or more parts if you have more things to be done)

Answer (score 1):

So here is my solution based on the suggestion above:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Running second pipeline
  inputs:
       targetType: 'inline'
       script: |
        Write-Host "Triggering pipeline..."
        $connectionToken= "$(PAT)"

        $base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
        $PipelineUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/YourOrganization/yourProject/_apis/pipelines/${{ parameters.pipelineId }}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1" 
        Write-Host "Pipeline url: $PipelineUrl"
        $body ="{ 
         `"resources`":{
                `"repositories`":{
                    `"self`":{`"refName`":`"refs/heads/${{ parameters.branch }}`"
                    }
                 }
            }
        }"       
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PipelineUrl -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method POST
        Write-Host "Response: $response"
        $BuildUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/YourOrganization/yourProject/_apis/build/builds/$($response.Id)?api-version=6.1-preview.6"
        Write-Host  $BuildUrl
        
        $TimeoutAfter = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 15
        $WaitBetweenPolling = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 10
        $Timeout = (Get-Date).Add($TimeoutAfter)
        do
        {
        $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $BuildUrl -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
        Write-Host $Response.status
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $WaitBetweenPolling.Seconds
        }
        while ((($Response.status -eq "notStarted") -or ($Response.status -eq "inProgress")) -and ((Get-Date) -lt $Timeout))
        
        if ($Response.result -ne "succeeded")
        {
            Write-Host $Response.result
            exit 1
        }
```

parameter for pipeline id: `pipelineId: $(resources.pipeline.resource.pipelineId)`

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with using extensions, the [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks&ssr=false#overview) you can get in the marketplace should support all of your requirements.

It lets you trigger another pipeline, with an option to wait for it, and options about how to treat failures of that pipeline if you do wait. So you can use that to trigger a build, wait for it, and succeed / fail based on if the build succeeds / fails.